# stop script and continue with mouse click

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a highcharts script that computes average in a chart and draws a line showing the avg.
I would like to have the line drawn when the user clicks the mouse, but don't know where to put the code for that.

```
beforeDrawSeries: function(series, seriesOptions, tempChart, seriesIndex)
{
  var totalValue = 0;
  // First, find the average value for the series
  for ( var i = 0; i < series.data.length; i++ )
  {
    totalValue += series.data[i].y;
  }
  aveValue = totalValue / series.data.length;
  for ( var j = 0; j < series.data.length; j++ )
  {
    // Find out if this data point is above average
    if ( series.data[j].y <= aveValue )
    {
      continue;
    }
    //een muisklik
    //return;
    //object.onclick=function();
    //continue;

    // The data point is above average. Color it green
    //var pointOptions = seriesOptions.data[j];
    //pointOptions.color = 'green';
  }
},
afterRendering: function(myChart)
{
  var chart=myChart.getCore();

  var mySeries = chart.series[0];

  // Assuming aveValue was set in the beforeDrawSeries function,
  // draw a plot line at the average value.
  mySeries.yAxis.addPlotLine({
    color: 'orange',
    width: 2,
    value: aveValue,
    id: 'averageValuePlotLine',
    zIndex: 2
  });
}
```

Comment: In the highcharts you can use [addSeries](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.addSeries) which allows to add serie to chart, dynamically.